# Removing specific text from string before entrance into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

Hi guys i have an PHP array that is coming from an rss feed with 2 sets of data. title's and descriptions.

(example print of array, i want to edit all of the description items in the array not just one index)

```
[2] => ('Remembrance','Release Date: Thursday 19th April 2012')
```

How would I manipulate the description string to remove "Release Date: " before its entrance into a mysql table?

This is my other code:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('rss.xml');
$title = $rss->xpath('//title');  //finding the title tags in the xml document and loading into variable
$description = $rss->xpath('//description');

$rows=array();

foreach($result as $title){
  $rows[]="('".mysql_real_escape_string($title)."','".mysql_real_escape_string(array_shift($description))."')";
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Films (Film_Name, Film_Release) VALUES ".implode(',',$rows));
print_r($rows);
```

Comment: Where's the array coming from?

Comment: from an RSS feed, updated with the full code

Answer (score 2):

You are you `str_ireplace` case insensitive

Example

```
$rows = array ();
$array = array (); // So many array
$array [2] = array (
        'Remembrance',
        'Release Date: Thursday 19th April 2012' 
); // Sample array Value

foreach ( $array as $detail ) {
    $title = $detail [0];
    $desc = str_ireplace ( "Release Date:", "", $detail [1] );
    $desc = rim($desc);
    $rows [] = sprintf ( "('%s','%s')", mysql_real_escape_string ( $title ), mysql_real_escape_string ( $desc )   );
}

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Films (Film_Name, Film_Release) VALUES ".implode(',',$rows));
print_r($rows);
```

Comment: How would i do that replacement on all of the array, not just index 2?

Comment: The rows array is populated already with 200 items, i have tried your way and when i go to print it, there is nothing there. the only code i removed was the "$array [2] = array(" bit as that was just a sample?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply nedd to remove "Release Date: " string use `str_replace('Release Date: ', '', 'Release Date: Thursday 19th April 2012');`

Use `preg_replace()` if your data is dynamic: `preg_replace('#^[^\:] #', '', 'Release Date: Thursday 19th April 2012');`